# Why can't you change your vote after X days?

Tags: discussion

I don't get it. I'd like to remove my downvote against an answer on this question: [Use SSH hostname aliases in browser](https://serverfault.com/questions/478263/use-ssh-hostname-aliases-in-browser/500036#500036)

But I can't. Someone has actually coded a feature to prevent you doing this after some time threshold.

Why?

Comment: Side note: People with high rep get random downvotes all the time. They really wont give it a second thought. Noob tend to freak out however, so better to be careful around them.

Comment: Ok, a couple of people are making the assumption that I'm motivated by others' hurt feelings. It's actually more about correctness: I consider the downvote an error, and I want to correct it.

Comment: One workaround to level it back out...just downvote every other answer. ;)

Answer (score 5):

It's not X days, it's 5 minutes...

(In principle, this question belongs on meta.SO, but I think it's worth having an answer here that doesn't require people to go looking over there.)

As far as I can tell, [this answer of Jeff's](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18046/130540) (one of the SO founders, though no longer part of the company) is still the official reason: they don't want people to downvote a post to make it look bad, post their own answer (which will look better because it's not -1), then later take the downvote away.

There are a [number](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80762/why-do-votes-get-locked) of [questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited) about [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94567/you-last-voted-on-this-answer-6-mins-ago-locked-too-short) on meta.SO, but despite some good arguments against locking votes after 5 minutes, SO Inc. thinks it's fine the way it is, so it's not going to change.

There is a laborious workaround: edit the post then change your vote.  But that only works if you have enough rep to edit w/out your edit being reviewed.

So basically, don't worry about it.  Since Iain's answer is the only one with a downvote, it's obvious that that's the vote you'd like to change.  But it's just one downvote and since he gave an answer you'd ruled out your downvote it arguably appropriate and - unlike some SE sites - I don't think SF has people who go nuts about every single downvote.

TL;DR: Don't worry about it, just move on.

Comment: Ah. Jeff Atwood. Again. Should have guessed. \ Anyway, I may have misunderstood the downvotee's answer, and maybe he was actually proposing something similar to what I gave as my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Yep. Because the *theory* goes:

- This is a poor answer, I will give it a -1
- If they want to rid themselves of the -1's, then they should improve their answer with an edit
- If they edit it, everyone who has previously voted can re-cast their vote
- If they don't edit it, then the original reasoning for your vote still stands

See for more info:

- [Request change in behaviour: Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19021/request-change-in-behaviour-vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited)
- [Vote too old to be changed, unless post is edited](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6250/vote-too-old-to-be-changed-unless-post-is-edited)

Comment: Vote for my answer, now with 3x more opinion!

Comment: I can't decide if I should leave my downvote in place to illustrate how stupid the tactical downvoting justification is...

Comment: Nooooooooooooooo my first ever negative scored answer

Comment: I'd forgotten the bit about how a 0 answer shows up before a -1...

Comment: If they don't edit it, then the original **possibly mistaken** reasoning for your vote still stands

Comment: @SteveBennett - correct. Not saying I agree with it, but I remember when it first came up and honestly - it doesn't cause too many issues. Just be glad it happened to such a high rep user who is already cynical and jaded, and so can probably survive a single downvote :)

Comment: You should see it over on SciFi.SE  I've seen whining from 5 of the top 8 users when they get a downvote.

Comment: -1, excellent experience, would downvote again.

Comment: Oh, darn, I wish I could take my downvote away now that my answer has benefited from being more prominent.  It really hurts me not to be able to...

Comment: You're eligible for a [badge](http://meta.serverfault.com/badges/38/peer-pressure) now :)

Comment: I thought the theory was - **'Take time to think before voting'**.  Be certain that the question is good or bad before you cast a vote.